# Calling execv inside a QProcess triggers finished() signal under Windows only

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote this example to illustrate a difference between linux and windows on process handling.

My main application starts a sub-app by calling QProcess::start(). If this sub-process restarts itself by calling execv (_execv under Windows), the finished() signal is triggered on the top application only under Windows. In my case, this is unexpected.

Is there a way to avoid this signal, or this is a QProcess bug?

Mathieu

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

   connect( ui->pushButtonStart, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( start() ) ) ;
   connect( ui->pushButtonRestart, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( restart() ) ) ;
   connect( &m_process, SIGNAL( finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus) ),
            this, SLOT( finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus) ) ) ;

   m_process.setProcessChannelMode( QProcess::MergedChannels );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}

void
MainWindow::start()
{
   m_process.start( qPrintable( QApplication::applicationFilePath() ) ) ;
}

void
MainWindow::restart()
{
   char *argv[2] ;
   argv[0] = strdup( QApplication::applicationFilePath().toStdString().c_str() ) ;
   argv[1] = NULL ;
   execv( qPrintable( QApplication::applicationFilePath() ), argv ) ;
}

void
MainWindow::finished
(
   int                  exitCode,
   QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus
)
{
   qDebug() << "Finished!" ;
}
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have an exact equivalent of the Unix `exec` functionality. On Windows one process ends and another starts; on Unix there is only ever one process.